# Jinja-like for Pdf in Python

Tags: python, pdf-generation, jinja2

I am looking for the best accurate tool for PDF in Python that works like Jinja does for HTML.

What are your suggestions?

Comment: If you are familiar with the Jinja framework I just added an answer you might find useful.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As answered by jbochi, ReportLab is the foundation for almost all Python projects that generate PDF.

But for your needs you might want to check out [Pisa / xhtml2pdf](http://www.xhtml2pdf.com/).  You would generate your HTML with a Jinja template and then use Pisa to convert the HTML to PDF. Pisa is built on top of ReportLab.

**Edit:** another option I'd forgotten about is [wkhtmltopdf](http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/)

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at [ReportLab Toolkit](http://www.reportlab.com/opensource/).

You can use templates only with the commercial version, though.

Comment: You're right and it is a problem since I would like to work from a template in pdf format.

Comment: Maybe it's an overkill, but you could use Jinja to generate the text and the toolkit to convert the text to pdf.

Comment: @jbochi: Not overkill, IMO.  I think this solution works very well.

Answer (score 3):

There's now a new kid on the block called [WeasyPrint](http://weasyprint.org/).

Answer (score 3):

I had exactly the same requirement as the OP. Unfortunately WeasyPrint wasn't a viable solution, because I needed very exact positioning and barcode support. After a few days of work I finished a reportlab XML wrapper with Jinja2 support.

The code can be found on GitHub
including an example [XML](https://github.com/badzong/pypdfml/blob/master/pypdfml/templates/example.xml) wich generates the following [PDF](https://github.com/badzong/pypdfml/blob/master/example.pdf?raw=true).

Answer (score 2):

What about python/jinja to rst/html and html/rst to pdf using either [rst2pdf](http://code.google.com/p/rst2pdf/) or [pandoc](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/).

Both of these have worked well for me but. like plaes, I may try [Weasyprint](http://weasyprint.org/) in the future.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use existing PDF as template, without altering original document, you can use Dhek template editor, which allows to define area (bounds, name, type) in a separate template file.

Template is saved in JSON format so that it can be parsed in Python, to fill areas over PDF and generate the final document (e.g. with values from Web form).

See documentation at https://github.com/applicius/dhek .

[EDIT]

Initial answer was from the author of dhek.
I have used this tool and this is great if your form has not been generated in the usual way (it even works on PDF done from images).

After you downloaded, unzipped, and run DHEK (no install needed, it is portable), you can select areas and given them a name:

[image: DHEK Areas]

You can then save the "mapping" to JSON so you can get the positions and dimensions of the areas:

```json
{
    "pages": [
        {
            "areas": [
                {
                    "name": "FirstName",
                    "x": 198.48648648648648,
                    "type": "text",
                    "y": 151.22779922779924,
                    "height": 15.75289575289574,
                    "width": 181.15830115830119
                },
                {
                    "name": "LastName",
                    "x": 195.33590733590734,
                    "type": "text",
                    "y": 176.43243243243245,
                    "height": 18.115830115830107,
                    "width": 185.0965250965251
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "format": "dhek-1.0.13"
}
```

You can then use these positions with `reportlab` to create a PDF that contains the text:

```py
from reportlab.pdfgen.canvas import Canvas


def write_text(
    canvas: Canvas, txt: str, x: float, y: float, height: float, in_middle: bool = True
) -> None:
    """Write text in a form (in middle of height)"""
    if canvas.bottomup:
        y = canvas._pagesize[1] - y
    canvas.drawString(x, y + height / 2, txt)


def create_overlay(overlay_path: str):
    """
    Create the data that will be overlayed on top
    of the form that we want to fill
    """
    c = Canvas(overlay_path, bottomup=0)  # DHEK has (0,0) at top-left
    write_text(c, "Mike", 198.48648648648648, 151.22779922779924, 15.75289575289574)
    write_text(c, "Jagger", 195.33590733590734, 176.43243243243245, 18.115830115830107)
   
    c.save()


create_overlay("form_overlay.pdf")
```

You can then use any tool / pdf library (e.g. `pdfrw`) to merge the two in a single page:

```py
import pdfrw

def merge_pdfs(form_pdf, overlay_pdf, output):
    """
    Merge the specified fillable form PDF with the
    overlay PDF and save the output
    """
    form = pdfrw.PdfReader(form_pdf)
    olay = pdfrw.PdfReader(overlay_pdf)

    for form_page, overlay_page in zip(form.pages, olay.pages):
        merge_obj = pdfrw.PageMerge()
        overlay = merge_obj.add(overlay_page)[0]
        pdfrw.PageMerge(form_page).add(overlay).render()

    writer = pdfrw.PdfWriter()
    writer.write(output, form)


merge_pdfs("form.pdf", "form_overlay.pdf", "form_filled.pdf")
```

(last part of code to create Overlay and Merge is coming from the Excellent blog "Mouse vs Python": https://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2018/05/22/filling-pdf-forms-with-python/)

Answer (score 1):

What more accurate tool for PDF in Python that works like Jinja than Jinja itself?

You just have to make sure that the `Jinja` block, variable, and comment identification strings do not conflict with the `LaTeX` commands. Once you change the `Jinja` environment to mimic the `LaTeX` environment you're ready to go!

Here's a snippet that works out of the box:

**Python Source:** `./create_pdf.py`

```
import os, jinja2
from jinja2 import Template

latex_jinja_env = jinja2.Environment(
    block_start_string    = '\BLOCK{',
    block_end_string      = '}',
    variable_start_string = '\VAR{',
    variable_end_string   = '}',
    comment_start_string  = '\#{',
    comment_end_string    = '}',
    line_statement_prefix = '%%',
    line_comment_prefix   = '%#',
    trim_blocks           = True,
    autoescape            = False,
    loader                = jinja2.FileSystemLoader(os.path.abspath('./latex/'))
)
template = latex_jinja_env.get_template('latex_template.tex')

# populate a dictionary with the variables of interest
template_vars  = {}
template_vars['section_1'] = 'The Section 1 Title'
template_vars['section_2'] = 'The Section 2 Title'

# create a file and save the latex
output_file = open('./generated_latex.tex', 'w')
# pass the dictionary with variable names to the renderer
output_file.write( template.render( template_vars ) )
output_file.close()
```

**Latex Template:** `./latex/latex_template.tex`

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\section{Example}
An example document using \LaTeX, Python, and Jinja.

% This is a regular LaTeX comment
\section{\VAR{section_1}}
\begin{itemize}
\BLOCK{ for x in range(0,3) }
  \item Counting: \VAR{x}
\BLOCK{ endfor }
\end{itemize}

\#{This is a long-form Jinja comment}
\BLOCK{ if subsection_1_1 }
\subsection{ The subsection }
This appears only if subsection_1_1 variable is passed to renderer.
\BLOCK{ endif }

%# This is a short-form Jinja comment
\section{\VAR{section_2}}
\begin{itemize}
%% for x in range(0,3)
  \item Counting: \VAR{x}
%% endfor
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

Now simply call: `$> python ./create_pdf.py`

**Resulting Latex Source:** `./generated_latex.tex`

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\section{Example}
An example document using \LaTeX, Python, and Jinja.

% This is a regular LaTeX comment
\section{The Section 1 Title}
\begin{itemize}
  \item Counting: 0
  \item Counting: 1
  \item Counting: 2
\end{itemize}

\section{The Section 2 Title}
\begin{itemize}
  \item Counting: 0
  \item Counting: 1
  \item Counting: 2
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

**Generated Pdf:**

[image]

**References:**

- [About Django's syntax conflict with LaTex](https://web.archive.org/web/20121024021221/http://e6h.de/post/11/)
- [About latex templates](http://eosrei.net/articles/2015/11/latex-templates-python-and-jinja2-generate-pdfs)
- [About passing a `dict` to `render_template`](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/flask/2016-February/000250.html)

Comment: How do you actually write to pdf?

Comment: the script above returns the source code, so use whichever latex compiler you prefer.

Comment: Yes, I found it in the meanwhile using `pdflatex` :)

Answer (score 0):

... There is also the library `pdfjinja` that is for this purpose: https://github.com/rammie/pdfjinja

It is using annotations to create template values.

In my use case, I didn't have a PDF with proper form fields so the solution suggested by cchantep was more suitable.