# Combining head, body and footer in HTML (or with CSS?)

Tags: python, html, css, weasyprint

I have two separate files called `head.html` and `footer.html`, each of which has several formatting options. In a python script, I am processing some text for the `body`:

```
sometext=inspect.cleandoc(f'''
  <body>
  This is some text.
  </body>
''')
Html_file= open('path/to/my/output.html',"w")
Html_file.write(sometext)
Html_file.close()
```

How do I:

1. Include the `head.html` and `footer.html` in my `output.html` in python, with the body in the middle? I was thinking, perhaps I can open `head.html` > write to `output.html`, open this file with `open( ... , 'a')` > write the footer. But perhaps there is a better way?
2. I am a bit confused as to how to use the CSS together with the html and my text generated in python. I understand how to write each of these, but not really sure how to get them to work together.

My goal is to use the `head.html`, body, `footer.html` in a single `html` file, and then convert it to PDF using `weasyprint`.

Comment: are you writing a templating app? any reason not to use jinja?

Comment: Is simply using three consecutive `Html_file.write()` calls not an option?

Comment: @deadvoid, just writing an pdf based on some parsed text to be honest. I'm using the HTML as a way to have the template. Thanks to your comment I [arrived here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2064936/jinja-like-for-pdf-in-python). Perhaps I should look into it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This script should do what you describe:

```
# open output file
Html_file= open('path/to/my/output.html',"w")

# write from header file to output file
with open('path/to/my/header.html') as header_file:
    for line in header_file:
        Html_file.write(line)

# write body
sometext=inspect.cleandoc(f'''
  <body>
  This is some text.
  </body>
''')
Html_file.write(sometext)

# write from footer file to output file
with open('path/to/my/footer.html') as footer_file:
    for line in footer_file:
        Html_file.write(line)

# close output file
Html_file.close()
```